# what is the problem in my ' index.py' code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, flask

I am trying to create a CRUD app using flask and mysql.I try to display to form one for student-login and one for tteacher-login. the form are display by hitting on buuttons "Std-Login" and "Teach-Login".
When I run the code on console it is showing -----
Traceback (most recent call lost):
@app.route('stdLog',methods=['POST','GET']
AssertionError:view function mapping is overwriting and existing endpoint function:home

```js
from flask import Flask,session,render_template,request
import os
import mysql.connector
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app=Flask(__name__)
# app.secret_key=os.urandom(24)
bcrypt=Bcrypt(app)


mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
 host="localhost",
 user="root",
 password="",
 db="mydatabase"
 )



@app.route('/')
def home():
 return render_template('home.html')






@app.route('/stdLog',methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
 if request.method=='POST':
  mycursor=mydb.cursor()
  pwHash=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])
  sql="insert into student (name,password) values (%s,%s)"
  val=(request.form['name'],pwHash)
  mycursor.execute(sql,val)
  mydb.commit()
  print(mycursor.rowcount,"student's record inserted")
 return 'ok'



@app.route('/teacherLog',methods=['POST','GET'])
def teacher():
 if request.method == 'POST':
  mycursor=mydb.cursor()
  pwHash=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['tpassword'])
  sql="insert into teacher(tname,tpassword) values(%s,%s)"
  val=(request.form['name'],pwHash)
  mycursor.execute(sql,val)
  mydb.commit()
  print(mycursor.rowcount,"teacher's recored Inserted")
 return 'Inserted'


if __name__=='__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="mystd()">Std-Login</button>
 <button onclick="myteach()">Teach-Login</button>


 <div id="std"  align="center">
   <form method="post" action="/stdLog" >
     Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
     Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="std">
    </form>
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>

 
 <!-- <div id="teach"  >
  <form method="post" action="/teacherLog" >
   Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
   Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="teacher">
  </form>
 </div> -->

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function mystd()
   {
    var s=document.getElementById("std");
    if(s.style.display == "none"){
     s.style.display = "block";
    }else{
     s.style.display = "none";
    }
   }

   function myteach()
   {
    var t=document.getElementById("teach");
    if(t.style.display == "none"){
     t.style.display = "block";
    }else{
     t.style.display = "none";
    }
   }
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: `route` sets up a two way mapping between url and function name. So "/" <-> `home()` and "/stdLog" <-> `home()` cannot work.

Comment: what should I do,to remove this problem? Mr Menno Hölscher

Comment: Rename one of the functions. I would suggest  standard_log() for the "/stdLog" route. "home()" is not a logical name for handling that route. See J. Timm's answer.

Comment: Yes I got your point.Thnx Mr  Menno Hölscher.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you are overwriting and existing endpoint function: home
Change the route /stdLog fuction to: `def home2():`  or  `def stdLog():`

```
 @app.route('/stdLog',methods=['POST','GET'])
    def stdLog():
        if request.method=='POST':
            mycursor=mydb.cursor()
            pwHash=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.form['password'])
            sql="insert into student (name,password) values (%s,%s)"
            val=(request.form['name'],pwHash)
            mycursor.execute(sql,val)
            mydb.commit()
            print(mycursor.rowcount,"student's record inserted")
        return 'ok'
```

Hope this helps you.